# Selenium & Python (looping through a password list)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of strings that I am looking to enter in a password field using selenium and Python 2.7x. Below is my code:

```
# album is a URL
def password_attempt(album):
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1")
    fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9150)
    fp.update_preferences()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
    driver.get(album)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("pwd")
    for password in password_list:
        elem.send_keys(password)
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        if album in driver.current_url:
            continue
        else:
            return driver.current_url
```

This code doesn't run and I get an error returned when it's run. In essence, when a password from the list is entered, if the password is incorrect, the page simply reloads with the same URL as the stem and a few random characters at the end of the URL. I'm then looking to move on to the next password in the list and try that. If the password is indeed accepted, the page then redirects to a new page with a new URL that doesn't contain any content from the original URL.

So the original URL may be `http://www.myalbum.com` and if an incorrect password is entered, it redirects to `http://www.myalbum.com/id=12344`. If a correct password is entered however, it redirects to `http://www.abc124.com`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\code.py", line 203, in <module>
    thumbnail_identifier()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\code.py", line 134, in thumbnail_identifier
    new_album = password_attempt(album)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\code.py", line 186, in password_attempt
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 303, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 385, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python2.7.8\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:8329:1)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpbibio4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:7922:10)
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpbibio4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8957:11)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpbibio4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11618:15)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpbibio4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11635:11)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpbibio4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11640:7)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/dell/appdata/local/temp/tmpbibio4/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11582:5)
```

Any help?

**UPDATE:** I restructed my code as below:

```
for password in password_list:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("pwd")
    elem.send_keys(password)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    if album in driver.current_url:
        continue
    else:
        return driver.current_url
```

A segment from the error is below:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
```

Comment: According to the docs http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException if you get this exception, either your selector is bad or the page hasn't finished loading, in which case you can use a wait wrapper to wait for the element to appear.